# SQL IF ELSE insert into #temp table problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario I am unsure how to resolve. Below I have an if else statement along with inserting data into a temp table.

```
IF @code= 'All'
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
        SELECT * 
        INTO #temp
        FROM #tempCity
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
        SELECT * 
        INTO #temp
        FROM #tempCity
        WHERE [City_Code] = @code
    END
```

It's worth noting that I do need the table `#temp` to have the same name in both conditions since I will use it later and what may be inserted, may differ from case to case which is why I haven't defined `#temp`.

I get an error message stating which is understandable in this case:

```
There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.
```

Does anyone know a way I may resolve this subtle issue?

Comment: Drop temp table using `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use Boolean logic :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp)
   DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM #tempCity
WHERE (@code= 'All' OR [City_Code] = @code);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can probably dispense with the `IF`:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM #tempCity
WHERE @code = 'All' OR [City_Code] = @code;
```

Second, the problem is a *compile* time error.  That is, the `SELECT INTO` is failing because the table exists.  You could use `GO` to solve this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
GO

SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM #tempCity
WHERE @code = 'All' OR [City_Code] = @code;
```

But that will not work in a stored procedure, function, or trigger.  Another option is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;

EXEC '
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM #tempCity
WHERE @code = ''All'' OR [City_Code] = @code
';
```

But I think the best solution is to use a table variable.  These will be deleted when out of scope.  That means that you can declare them and assume that they don't exist.  Then use `INSERT` to add data.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually compiler error. If you try something like this:

```
DROP TABLE #test;
GO

DECLARE @Code int;

IF @Code IS NULL BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #test (ID int);
END ELSE BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #test (ID int);
END

GO
DROP TABLE #test;
```

Assuming `#test` never existed to start with you'll get the errors:

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#test', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
There is already an object named '#test' in the database.
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 15
Cannot drop the table '#test', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

This actually shows that `#test` was never created. This is because you try to create `#test` twice in the same statement and the compiler doesn't like it.

You're probably better off using a `WHERE` like this as result:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM #TempCity
WHERE City_Code = @Code OR @Code = 'All;
```

Although you could use dynamic SQL, the temporary object would only persist within the session created by `sp_executesql`; making it useless to you.